# regular expression using Negative Lookahead and Negative Lookbehind to capture string in multiline xml

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds, negative-lookbehind

i have this xml , using Negative Lookahead and Negative Lookbehind i try to capture the first occurrence fo the version tag so in my case it is :

```
<version>mainapp.1.4</version>
```

i tried this :

```
 (?<!^<parent>)<version>(?!<\/parent>)
```

but still it gives me all the version tags 
what im doing wrong here ?

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" >
        <modelVersion>55.0.0</modelVersion>

        <parent>
            <groupId>org.test.proj</groupId>
            <artifactId>test-invoker</artifactId>
            <version>invoker.0.4</version>
        </parent>

        <groupId>org.test.proj.assent</groupId>
        <artifactId>mainapp</artifactId>
        <version>mainapp.1.4</version>
        <packaging>pom</packaging>
        <name>main app 1</name>

        <properties>
            <app-name>Testing App</app-name>
        </properties>

        <dependencyManagement>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.prod.db</groupId>
                    <artifactId>srver-db</artifactId>
                    <version>${project.version}</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </dependencyManagement>
        </project>
```

Comment: Why don't you use an `xml` parser?

Comment: This is how you do it with a PCRE pattern: `(?s)<parent>.*?</parent>(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|<version>.*?</version>` (see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/9UgeDe/2)). Was that your question today about just grep and sed?

Comment: Any feedback? What tool/programming language is it?